# QGIS Profile Tool dependencies

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt4

I'm trying to install the Profile Tool on QGIS 2.14 (newest version present in ubuntugis ppa) and i get this error:
**'No module named PyQt.QtCore'**  
I have installed the following packages:
python3-pyqt4, python-qt4-dev, pyqt4-dev-tools, python-pyqt5, python3-pyqt5, pyqt5-dev, pyqt5-dev-tools
but the plugin is still not working.

Does anyone know how to fix this situation?

Comment: Do other python plugins work?